# Bounding box of path wrong position

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have a problem with several path's that I have saved in my database. It turns out that the bounding box is completely displaced from the object. Someone help me?

[image]

Path example:

```
{"objects":[{"type":"path","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":200,"top":100,"width":162.33,"height":162.33,"fill":"#D1D3D4","overlayFill":null,"stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":0.84,"scaleY":0.84,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"path":[["M",162.329,81.164],["c",0,44.826,-36.338,81.165,-81.164,81.165],["C",36.338,162.329,0,125.99,0,81.164],["C",0,36.338,36.338,0,81.165,0],["C",125.99,0,162.329,36.338,162.329,81.164],["z"]],"pathOffset":{"x":-81.165,"y":-81.165}}],"background":"#f7f7f7"}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3q61vmef/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error. Error is in `pathOffset` property. Need to change `x` and `y` values to zero by replacing like this:

```
"pathOffset":{"x":0,"y":-81.165}
```

to:

```
"pathOffset":{"x":0,"y":0}
```

Thank you.